# Resizable Master Page and Content Place Holder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, c#-4.0, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive website using ASP.NET. My website will be having a common Master page and multiple ContentPlace holders. I need help with the Javascript, CSS and Jquery functions which need to be used. I searched on the net. But none of the options helped. Please help.

Comment: What sort of help do you need? (You said you need help with javascript, css, etc. but you didn't say what sort of help is required.)

Comment: Show some code or advance that you are doing .... we are here to help not to do

Answer (score 1):

Place the content placeholder inside a DIV or some other container element. Give that container element a width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following techniques:

```
<div class="sample">
Your Contents Here
</div>

<style>
  .sample {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/* This is for small screen devices*/
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .sample {
    width: 764px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
}
```